# Find a File bar not finding all files in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I have a Document Library with a lot of files that are created/modified by me.

However when I use the bar "Find a File" only one of these files is coming as a result. There should be multiple files

Comment: When did you add those files? and are you searching for complete word or just 2-3 characters?

Comment: The files are relativly old. they have been added a couple months ago. Well Im just writing my first name but on modified by is given my full name

Comment: Please screenshot of what you search text you are using and files screenshot which you are expecting.

Comment: Are you trying to search based on Modified by person? If so, you can also filter the modified by column from library view.

Comment: Yes, in this case Im trying to search based on Modified by person. How would I go if I wanted to use the search bar based on who uploaded the file. The users prefer writing their name on the "Find a file bar " and looking for files that way rather than using views

Comment: Try using wild card(*) search like `JohnD*`.

Comment: Its weird. I have two files that are modified by me and along those files there are a lot of folder. When I search by my name those files are not showing only folders

Answer (score 0):

You can click "Include" to check if there is a difference.
[image]
If this issue still exists, you can try to reindex your document library via Library settings->Advanced settings->Reindex document library. Then wait for crawling.